# Converting C++ Pointer Math to C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I'm currently working on a project that requires converting some C++ code to a C# environment. For the most part, it's actually pretty straightforward, but I'm currently converting some lower-level memory manipulation functions and running into some uncertainty as to how to proceed.

In the C++ code, I've got a lot of instances of things like this (obviously quite simplified):

```
void SomeFunc(unsigned char* myMemoryBlock)
{
    AnotherFunc(myMemoryBlock);

    AnotherFunc(myMemoryBlock + memoryOffset);
}

void AnotherFunc(unsigned char* data)
{
    // Also simplified - basically, modifying the
    // byte pointed to by data and then increasing to the next item.
    *data = 2;
    data++;

    *data = 5;
    data++;

    // And so on...
}
```

I'm thinking that in C#, I've basically got to treat the "unsigned char*" as a byte array (byte[]). But to perform a similar operation to the pointer arithmetic, is that essentially just increasing a "currentIndex" value for accessing the byte array? For something like AnotherFunc, I guess that means I'd also need to pass in a starting index, if the starting index isn't 0?

Just want to confirm this is how it should be done in C#, or if there's a better way to make that sort of conversion. Also, I can't use the "unsafe" keyword in my current environment, so actually using pointers is not possible!

Comment: everytime I've seen code like this in C++ the myMemoryBlock was basically what we call an Class in C#.  Maybe converting this object to an object is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, context matters but I think what you said is correct.

Comment: Yes, you can replace your "unsigned char*" with a byte[] or char[] (depending on what you need).  And give an index instead of your memoryoffset (depending on the size of a "char" in c++ -> computation for memoryoffset can be different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like [@dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335858/dasblinkenlight) said, the C# (and Java) way to deal with arbitrary pointers to memory data blocks (which are usually byte or char arrays) is to add an additional `offset` parameter to the methods that access the data blocks.

It is also common to add a third `length` parameter. Thus the general form for a method `Foo()` that is passed a block of memory is:

```
// Operate on 'block', starting at index 'offset',
// for 'length' elements
//
int Foo(byte[] block, int offset, int length)
{ ... }
```

You see this all over the place in the C# library. Another form that is common for methods that operate on two memory blocks (e.g., copying one block to another, or comparing one block to another, etc.) is this:

```
// Operate on blocks 'src' starting at index 'srcOff',
// and on block 'dst' starting at 'dstOff',
// for a total of 'length' elements
//
int Bar(byte[] src, int srcOff, byte[] dst, int dstOff, int length)
{ ... }
```

For methods that expect to operate on an entire memory block (array), these generally look like this:

```
// Overloaded version of Foo() that
// operates on the entire array 'block'
//
int Foo(byte[] block)
{
    return Foo(block, 0, block.Length);
}
```

Comment: This did the trick for me! An additional complication that I ran into, which might be obvious: the type of pointer has an effect on the math being performed.

For example, incrementing an unsigned char pointer in C++ translates to incrementing the byte offset by 1 in C#, while incrementing a 32-bit integer pointer by one in C++ translates to incrementing the byte offset by 4 in C#.

Answer (score 3):

The two functions treat `myMemoryBlock` as if it represented an array. You could replace a single `myMemoryBlock` parameter with a pair of `myArray` and `myOffset`, like this:

```
void SomeFunc(char[] myArray)
{
    AnotherFunc(myArray, 0);

    AnotherFunc(myArray, memoryOffset);
}

void AnotherFunc(char[] data, int offset)
{
    // Also simplified - basically, modifying the
    // byte pointed to by data and then increasing to the next item.
    data[offset++] = 2;
    data[offset++] = 5;
    // And so on...
}
```

**Note:** C++ type `unsigned char` is often used as a stand-in for "untyped block of memory" (as opposed to "a block of memory representing character data"). If this is the case in your situation, i.e. the pointer points to memory that is not necessarily character, an array of `byte` would be a more appropriate choice.

Comment: Using `offset = 0` would allow for syntax slightly more like the above code, since the explicit use of zero would no longer be necessary

Comment: @Aravol That's an interesting idea. However, I would not default the offset in situations where an array replaces a pointer to make it explicit on the caller side that only a portion of the array will be of interest to the API.

Comment: Also keep in mind that `char` in C# is different from `char` in C++.  In C#, a `char` is a 16-bit value used to represent a unicode character.  It may be more appropriate to use `byte[]` here, but that does depend on the OP's needs.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for a comment! I added a note to mention `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

C# does away with pointers for the exact reasons of preventing pointer arithmetic (rather, the errors that pointer arithmetic is vulnerable to).

Generally any C++ memory block referred to by a pointer and memory offset is indeed best translated as an array in C# (hence why even C# arrays start with `[0]`).However, you should keep the array the same type as the underlying data  -`char[]` instead of `byte[]`. Because this is also a `char[]`, you should look at what the overall use of the function is and consider switching to a `string`.